# Natural embedding GL_n(C) -> C^{n^2} \ {0} induces zero on cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, algebraic-groups, lie-groups

The question looks like an exercise in elementary algebraic topology, but I didn't manage to solve it. I am considering this question because it is a toy example in a problem I'm thinking about.

Let's consider the natural embedding $GL_n(\mathbb C) \to \mathbb C^{n^2} \backslash \{0\}$. As was discussed [in this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18677/cohomology-rings-of-gl-nc-sl-nc), cohomology with rational coefficients of $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is an exterior algebra on generators in degrees 1, 3, ..., 2n-1 (one generator in each degree), whereas $\mathbb C^{n^2} \backslash \{0\}$ is homotopy equivalent to a sphere $S^{n^2-1}$.

I'd like to prove that the map induced on cohomology of degree $n^2 - 1$ is a zero map. 
Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\mathbb C^{n^2} \smallsetminus {0}$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^{2n^2-1}$, not $S^{n^2-1}$, and $\mathrm H^{2n^2-1}(GL_n(\mathbb C)) = 0$.

Comment: Just to be really pedantic, *n* should be at least 2.

Comment: Yes, for $n=1$ the two spaces coincide. Let me add that the reason why $\mathrm H^{2n^2-1}(GL_n(\mathbb C)) = 0$ is that $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is homotopy equivalent to the unitary group $U_n$, which has dimension $n^2$. Or, $\mathrm H^{i}(GL_n(\mathbb C)) = 0$ for $i > n^2$ because $GL_n(\mathbb C)$ is an affine variety of dimension $n^2$.

Comment: This matches with n^2=1+2+...+(2n-1), the degree of a top cohomology class in the exterior algebra H^*(GL_n(C)).

Comment: Another reason that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ has top cohomology in dimension $n^2$ is that is an affine algebraic variety of dimension $n^2$. (To see that $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is affine, write it as `$\{(g,x) \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n} \times \mathbb{C} : x \det g =1 \}$`.)